# Google Play : How do I access the "Target audience and content section of the Play Console "

Tags: android, console, playback

I've just received the following message from the Google Play Store :

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> We’re writing to let you know that you have not yet completed the
>   Target audience and content section of the Play Console for at least
>   one of your apps. All developers were asked to fill out this section
>   for all apps by September 1, 2019.
>
> Your app may be subject to removal from Google Play if you do not
>   provide this information in Play Console.

.. but I can't seem to find the "Target audience and content section of the Play Console " section anywhere in the Google Play Console.

Where is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Select your application from in google play console
- Click on Store Presence at left side panel expand it. Then click App Content you can see "Target audience and content"

**Store Presence -> App Content -> Target audience and content -> Start**

Comment: Where do I see the target audience age as a user from playstore?